# css text position styling not aligned

Tags: css

I am trying to implement something where my text width is identical to one another or very close for example. I have a few div tags with some text that is unchangeable react component that is injecting a variable into the div tag for example  {reactVar}

however my text that is returned aligns like so for mr following divs.

```
test
   test
  test
  tets
 tetstetetse
```

all of my text are not aligned accurately they are all over the place. Any suggestions to have them all the same width and aligned? I have tried text align center and margin auto and none work.

Comment: are there any spaces in the data E.G: "   test", can you please confirm there are no spaces, also the html and CSS is needed for giving a good solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for? You want all of the divs to be centered or left aligned? are they inside a parent div? Can you post your code? or create a fiddle demonstrating the problem?